# Bug reporting regarding HTML and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I believe I have found a bug in HTML / JavaScript, but I have no idea where to post this bug. Any information on where to post such bugs is appreciated.

The bug can be recreated as follows:

1. Go to [W3Schools Tryit Editor](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onblur_html)
2. Make sure you have some other tab open in the same window
3. Click on the input field to focus it
4. Click on a different tab in your browser
5. Depending on your browser, different effects will occur (all unwanted)

This has been tested in Chrome (it will give an infinitely repeating alert), on Firefox (it will give the alert, but not switch tabs when clicking the alert away), and on Edge (it will show that the new tab is selected in the tabs bar, but the rest of the page doesn't switchenter link description here).

Since this bug occurs in multiple browsers, and also since the bug occurs with sample code from w3schools, I believe that this bug is related to HTML / JavaScript more than to a specific browser.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a bug report for some site that has nothing to do with stackoverflow.

Comment: FYI "w3schools" is a private for-profit business and has absolutely nothing to do with web or Internet standards.

Answer (score 1):

W3Schools isn't affiliated with [W3C](https://www.w3.org/), the organisation who maintain the HTML specification. Nor are they affiliated with [Ecma International](https://www.ecma-international.org/), the organisation who maintain the JavaScript specification. Nor, for that matter, are they affiliated with any browser.

The code they've supplied here is their own code. It's not official by any stretch of the imagination: it's code that you or I could have written.

However that said, it looks like you have discovered a bug which affects multiple browsers. This is something you an report on the various browser channels if you so desire. Potorr has [already linked you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44001676/1317805) to a couple of these, which can be found by simply searching for something like "{browser name} bug tracker" with a search engine.

However you may consider instead posting directly on W3Schools' forum, as, after all, this is their code: http://w3schools.invisionzone.com/index.php?/forum/45-general.

Comment: I can't reproduce the behavior reported in the OP fwiw (*edit* in Firefox)

Comment: @Pointy the steps they've described result in an infinitely undismissable alert box when executed on Chrome on Windows. It doesn't even prompt the "do not show any more messages on this site" notice it usually gives - the only fix is to forcibly close the tab or close the browser entirely.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly I see it in Linux/Chrome too. But Firefox doesn't do anything unusual.